# in asp.net, how to force users to browse with one browser window at a given time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton

i have to implement a requirement that's kind of weird for web apps (intranet web app).

after an user login to the app, the user may press Ctrl + N to open the current page in a new window. this sounds perfectly normal except the business requirement is to prevent users from doing this. users must logoff before they can access to the app again with a different browser window/tab.

any ideas?

Comment: This is simply a bad requirement. If you've decided to use a web-based application, then you've decided to use an application that does not belong to you (the user's browser). It is outside of your control and ownership.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reliable way to do this over the public WWW. If you have control over the clients using your application you could write a WinForms application using the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx) control to host it and then you can control which keys are enabled.